# Is the Multi site functionality a viable option for Country and Language targeting?

Tags: multisite, user-registration, multi-language, subdomains

I am working on an eCommerce website, which only has the TLD Extension `.com` at present.

The website owner is keen on looking to expand the website, as to reach other Countries and Languages.  Since this is an experiment, I have suggested having Sub Domains created for now then look at investing in ccTLDs at a later date.  The Sub Domains being:

```
en-gb.example.com (UK Visitors who speak English)
fr-gb.example.com (UK Visitors who speak French)
en-ca.example.com (Canadian Visitors who speak English)
fr.ca.example.com (Canadian Visitors who speak French)
```

At present, I have set up different Sub Domains where each has its own WordPress installation.  Something that was achieved via FTP.

I then came across WordPress' Multisite feature, which seems to allows Sub Domain management within the WordPress Dashboard.  Something I feel would be easier for the website owner.  After installing the Multisite, I noticed the following limitations:

- Could only install one language version of WordPress;
- Users could not share their login credentials with the other Sub Domains within the Network.

With the above in mind, is it a case that the WordPress multisite is not a suitable option for what I am looking to achieve or is there a way to overcome the above limitations?

Comment: Take a look at this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/ With it you can choose backend and frontend language for each site of the network and even link posts/pages/products with each other.